# pandas .last only works on ascending sorted index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

When using df.last() on a dataframe with the datetimeIndex in descending order the whole dataframe is returned. Is that on purpose? If so, why?

I created a dataframe like:

```
select col1,date from table1 order by date desc
df = pd.read_sql(query,cnx)
df = df.set_index(['date'])
```

`df.last('1D')` returns the whole dataframe

`df.sort_index().last('1D')` works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `last` method pandas uses `index.searchsorted` method. Its name and commentaries in both numpy and pandas say that data (dataframe index in our case) should be sorted in ascending order. There is an option to supply `sorter` as one of `searchsorted` arguments. It could work if you had any access to `searchsorted` inside `last`. However, you can't supply any sorter to `last`.

So you have to sort index in ascending order to get correct results with `last`. Unfortunately, the feature is not described explicitly in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this.
Is there a way to bring this to the attention of the pandas documentation team? It would have saved me some time if it was documented.

Comment: @HansdeRidder I guess the only viable way is to start an issue on github. I believe github account is required to do so. There is also some mailing list and something called gitter - `https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md`.